# shell script for multiple strings multiple lines

Tags: shell

Hi i have an xml file where i need to search a string in a line if present replace that with something and search for the next string and replace that with the required .
I tried this

```
while read line
    do
    user=`echo $LINE |grep  "<?xml"`
    if [ $user == "<?xml" ]; then
      replace=utf-8
      user=`echo $LINE|sed "s/UTF-8/${replace}/"` >> $input_file
    fi
done
```

It is checking for only one string and for remaining how to do it.

how to check for the remaining also like , and do some checks and replace.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is missing `g` flag on the end of `sed` command.
I'm also not sure about `if` condition. Below is my example.

```
while read line
  do
  user=`echo $line |grep  "<?xml"`
  if [ -n "$user" ]; then
    replace="utf-8"
    user=`echo $line|sed "s/UTF-8/${replace}/g"`
    echo $user >> $input_file
  fi
done
```